# I can not connect to a Google Iot Core using node-red

Tags: node-red, pem

I am using node-red to communicate with Google Iot Core. I have already managed to communicate with the same Google Iot Core broker using the Python language, but now I want to use node-red. I installed node-red-contrib-google-iot-core and I've configured the broker and the PEM keys in the same way as in Python.

When I pulse "Deploy" it appears as disconnected and these errors appear:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined"
>   "Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line".

This is the structure of the PEM keys:

```
**Certificate**

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

...

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----



**Private Key** 

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

...

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 


**CA Certificate**

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

...

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

[image: Error messages]

Comment: Strange problems like this are often caused by unsupported versions of nodejs. What version does `node -v` report as being used on your node-red device?

Comment: Hello! First, thanks for your answer. I am using node-red in a Siemens IoT2040 device. I am using the version v6.12.3.

Comment: You should be able to find more detail in the node-red log.